# Как соединить содержимое контейнера и фон в одно целое?

Tags: html, css

Текст и бэкграунд "скролятся" отдельно друг от друга. Проблема решается при отключении свойства overflow-x в css, однако исчезает фон при этом.

Как сделать, чтобы содержимое контейнера не ездило при "скроллинге"?

```css
.clear {
        float: none;
        clear: both;
    }

.background-loyality {
    background: url("/products/loyality/images/images/loyality-background.png") top center no-repeat;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-top: 94px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container {
    width: 1170px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 330px;
    position: relative;
}
.background-loyality .main-container h1, h2, h3 {
    /* margin-top: 24px; */
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: #3c1a75;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: normal;
}

.background-loyality .main-container h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .title-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-picture {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 160px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-second-picture {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 655px;
    left: -30px;
}
.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-opp {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 320px;
    padding-right: 73px;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 710px;
}
.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-opp h3, h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
}


.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-opp ul li:before {
    content: '\25CF';
    color: white;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-opp  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-opp ul li {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-goals {
    line-height: 26px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-goals h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #3c1a75;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-goals ul li:before {
    content: '\25CF';
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-goals  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-goals ul li {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #656a74;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-goals h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.background-loyality .main-container .loyality-opp ul h4 {
    padding-top: 41px;
    /* margin-bottom: 11px; */
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="background-loyality">
            <div class="main-container">
                <h1>Программа лояльности</h1>
                    <p class="title-text">Мотивационная программа для стимулирования сотрудников к повышению показателей с возможным<br/>дальнейшим награждением</p>

                <div class="loyality-goals">
                    <h2>Цели:</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Стимулирование сотрудников на продажу</li>
                            <li>Увеличение доли продаж</li>
                            <li>Удержание сотрудников и повышение их<br/>лояльности к месту работы</li>
                            <li>Стимулирование сотрудников на приобретения<br/>новых компетенций</li>
                            <li>Увеличение производительности труда</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="loyality-picture">
                    <img src="images/images/program-display.png"> 
                </div>

                <div class="loyality-second-picture">
                    <img src="images/images/program-device.png">
                </div>

                <div class="loyality-opp">
                    <h3>Возможности:</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Создание простого и привлекательного сценария<br/> программы лояльности</li>
                            <li>Вовлечение сотрудников в коллективную работу</li>
                            <li>Сочетание различных типов мотиваций</li>
                            <li>Разработка как краткосрочной, так и долгосрочной<br/> программы мотивации</li>
                            <li>PUSH-уведомления (SMS/E-mail)</li>
                            <li>Система отчетности (Excel, CSV)</li>
                            <li>Возможность обратной связи</li>
                            <li>Контроль за поставленными и выполненными задачами</li> 
                        </ul>
                    <h3>Необходимое оборудование:</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>ПК, планшет, смартфон</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `background-size: cover;` может решит вашу проблему. Я локально проверив ваш код, ошибки не обнаружил, проверьте линки на ваши изображения

Comment: @WhyTry частично помогло. осталась полоска вторая со скролингом. как бы её ликвидировать.

Comment: попробуйте поиграться с `overflow` а именно с `overflow-x` или `overflow-y`, либо `width:100%` установить